# TheOdinProject: Installing rails [OS X / gem install rails / SSL Error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl

I am struggling to install `gem install rails` because constantly got back this text:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

[TheOdinProject / Step 2: Creating your first Ruby on Rails web application](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/web-development-101/lessons/your-first-rails-application) at this section I could not continue it.

Could anyone help in this ?

I am using:

- OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan
- `ruby -v`
  ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin15]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install a specific version, i.e gem install rails -v 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved it / but with sudo gem install rails.

It solved the entire case but some of them said it may cause some inaccurencies.

Anybody who knows about this things / please describe it why?